# Remove unwanted space under ul tag

Tags: html

I created a *navigationsbar* element, but under the bar is some space and I don't know how to remove it. The `div` element should be directly below the *navigationsbar* element. Could you please help me?

[This](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/nav) is my page.

Here is the code of the *navigationsbar* element:

```css
nav{
    text-align: right;
}

nav > ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

nav ul li > a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 7px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    background:linear-gradient( #FCFCFC, #C8CACB);
    border: 1px solid #CED7E3;
}

nav ul li > a:hover{
    background:linear-gradient( #C8CACB, #FCFCFC);
}
```

Comment: Remove the margin-bottom from `nav ul > li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the `margin-bottom: 10px` on your `li` that is causing the space. Remove that and it will be fine.

```
nav ul > li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px; <------ take out
}
```